# Use libcurl with --cert in PHP on mavericks

Tags: php, curl, ssl, osx-mavericks

After updating to MAC OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) libcurl has a few limitations. 
One limitation is, that client certificates can't be sent with the request any more (option --cert or -E):

http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2013-10/0036.html

In the link above, this is limitation number 4. As a workaround it states, that libcurl would be running with --cert option, if "you download the latest curl version and build it yourself".

**My questions are:**

1. how can I build libcurl myself on OS X?
2. Is it possible to use the self-built libcurl in the preinstalled PHP in Mavericks?
3. If yes, where (e.g. in php.ini?) do I state, which libcurl should be used?

*Note: I know, that some sources recommend using the certificates from keychain tool, but I need the solution for my development environment, that can be run on the server as well – which is an Apache on Ubuntu where I have to provide the certificate as file (PEM or P12)*

Thank you very much for any help.